# wrap_content does not work for TextView in Android 4.0

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a LinearLayout that contains 2 TexView with layout_height set to **wrap_content**. Normally if the TextView does not contain any data, its Height becomes 0 (that's what wrap_content does). This works as expected in Android 3.2, but in Android 4.0, it leaves an empty space !!
Any explanation please?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"> 

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I posted some code, just a classic linearLayout with 2 TextView

Comment: Where do you get empty spaces?

Comment: With api 8 and higher don't forget to use match_parent instead of fill_parent.

Comment: Empty space in the place of the TextView

Comment: I tried match_parent, it didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

By default TextView is initialized by empty string, so the height of TextView in your case is defined by textSize of empty string which is 25sp, so in fact it works properly. If you want to hide empty TextView use `visibility="gone"` attribute.